# How to send parameters to a WebSetup project through Command Line

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have created a web Setup project.In the UI of the setup there are fields to be filled,some are text boxes some are drop down Lists boxes all( Default ones). 
Example Fields: Virtual Directory,Application pool etc

I need to  set these parameters and install the setup thru Command prompt.
Setup has to be a silent installation.

I tried using commands like /quiet  /a /i etc of msiexec,But I wasn't able to send parameters and also Install the setup silently.

How do I send parameters thru command prompt ? and
How can I run the setup ( silent  Installation)  simultaneously ?

direct me in the right path.

Answer (score 2):

In case this is helpful to anyone, here's how I achieved this:

There are three things you can set in the default installer:

1. The website to install to
2. The virtual directoy to install to (beneath the chosen site)
3. The application pool to use

All three of these are exposed for use on the command line, as shown below:

```
msiexec.exe /i Installer.msi /q TARGETSITE="/LM/W3SVC/1" TARGETVDIR="VDIR" TARGETAPPPOOL="APPPOOL"
```

The only tricky one is the `TARGETSITE` property. To find out what argument to use, run the *.msi file once as follows:

```
installer.msi /l*
```

This will output a text log file, you can then go through a read that log to find out what argument you should use. It looks like there's a lot of other possible parameters too -- but those three are the ones that I needed.